# Move camera to selected Places location

Tags: android-fragments, android-maps-v2

In my app, I have both `SupportMapFragment` as well as `PlaceAutocompleteFragment` and the layout, **fragment_map** is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.FragmentB">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_width="340dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </fragment>
</LinearLayout>
```

And in my **FragmentB**, I use them like so:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // don't recreate fragment every time
    if (supportMapFragment == null && view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager()
                                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        //when successful, calls onMapReady()
        supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    //Place fragment
    autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getActivity().
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

    // Register a listener to receive callbacks when a place has been selected or an error has occurred
    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(this);
    return view;
}
```

I run into two issues:

1. camera doesn't move to the selected place, even though I can get the marker to that location
2. map fragment takes me back to my current location

I am certain I am running into fragment lifecycle issue but I am not sure if I should replace map fragment with place fragment and add it to the backstack whenever `onPlaceSelected()` is selected.

Answer (score 0):

I added logs for every fragment lifecycle call and noticed that `onResume` the map fragment overrides the place fragment because I check if the map client is connected or not so, adding this check,                          `if (!autocompleteFragment.isVisible()) {
            //if p
            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() &&
                    !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
            {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                Log.d(TAG, "onResume(), called mGoogleApiClient.connect()");
            }
        }` ensured place fragment had focus and hence the camera moved to the selected Places location.